# Correct newtype definition

Tags: haskell

I am wondering why the following is the correct implementation of the Pair type. Specifically, why `Pair b a` and not `Pair a b`?

```
newtype Pair b a = Pair { getPair :: (a,b) }
```

To clarify, `Pair a b` doesn't work for the following:

```
instance Functor (Pair c) where  
fmap f (Pair (x,y)) = Pair (f x, y)
```

and I don't understand why.

In addition to a lot of the great answers below, I found doing the following in ghci helpful:

```
*Main> newtype Pair b a = Pair (a, b) deriving (Show, Eq)
*Main> :t Pair(True, "cat")
Pair(True, "cat") :: Pair [Char] Bool

*Main> newtype Pair a b = Pair (a, b) deriving (Show, Eq)
*Main> :t Pair(True, "cat")
Pair(True, "cat") :: Pair Bool [Char]
```

Comment: who says that this **is** the correct implementation - *correct* in what sense? I think you have seen this somewhere where you want to make an functor out of a pair for the first component rather than the second (or something like this) right?

Comment: @CarstenKönig: Probably [LYAH](http://learnyouahaskell.com/functors-applicative-functors-and-monoids).

Comment: @Zeta exactly - was to lazy to search for it - thanks :D

Comment: @jcm - yeah but it works with `fmap f (x,y) = (x,f y)` ;)

Comment: it does not work with `Pair a b` because now you define a functor `Pair a` with **fixed** a - but you want to keep `b` *fixed* - it's always the last part/type-variable ;) (just as in partial-application of functions)

Comment: straight from LYAH: "But it seems like there's no way to do something like that with (a,b) so that the type parameter a ends up being the one that changes when we use fmap." <- this is the reason for the `newtype` ;)

Comment: I guess I just don't understand why you would define Pair b a with the first component (a) in the second position and the second component (b) in the first position?

Comment: because when you define something as an instance of `Functor` you need something of kind `* -> *` (meaning you put in a type and get a type) - `Pair` is such a thing but of kind `* -> * -> *` (= `* -> (* -> *)`) and so you need to fix the first parameter - but of course the thing fixed should be the second component of your *pair* - therefore the flip - **think** of it as in curried functions and partial application but for types

Comment: Reminder: kinds where [introduced in chapter 8](http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses#kinds-and-some-type-foo).

Comment: I'm finding this really mind bending. Any suggestions on how to really grok this stuff?

Comment: yeah it can be hard - make sure you get the curryied/parital applied function stuff and then reread said chapter 8

Comment: @jcm: You shouldn't edit answers into a question. If you think that the GHCi commands provide more information than any current answer, feel free to post it and accept it (although you might need to wait for a certain amount of time). However, I think that the GHCi session shows the difference much better than my current answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're talking about the [definition in LYAH](http://learnyouahaskell.com/functors-applicative-functors-and-monoids):

```
newtype Pair b a = Pair { getPair :: (a,b) }
```

Note the paragraph that precedes it (emphasis mine):

> It turns out that writing the instance for that is kind of hard. With `Maybe`, we just say instance Functor Maybe where because only type constructors that take exactly one parameter can be made an instance of Functor. **But it seems like there's no way to do something like that with `(a,b)` so that the type parameter a ends up being the one that changes when we use `fmap`. To get around this, we can newtype our tuple in such a way that the second type parameter represents the type of the first component in the tuple:**

So, in this case we want the type of the (underlying) pair's *first* element  being the *last* type in the type constructor `Pair`. After all, we want to use `fmap` on the first argument in LYAH:

```
--                     b 
--                     |
--                     v  a isn't here… 
instance Functor (Pair c) where  
  -- but here!
  --fmap :: (a -> x) -> Pair c a -> Pair c x                        
    fmap f (Pair (x,y)) = Pair (f x, y)
```

You can of course change the definition to `newtype Pair b a = Pair { getPair :: (a,b) }`. But what happens in this case?

```
--                     a 
--                     |
--                     v  b isn't here… 
instance Functor (Pair c) where  

  -- but here!               v---- c ----v--------------------------+
  --fmap :: (b -> x) -> Pair c b -> Pair c x                        |
    fmap f (Pair (x,y)) = Pair (f x, y)                   --        |
                             -- ^^^ uh-oh - that doesn't seem right-+
```

Remember, your underlying type is now `(a,b)`. However, in your `Functor` instance `a` is now fixed, yet you try to apply `fmap` on that. That does not work. Instead, you have to use `fmap` on the second entry, which corresponds to `b` from the type constructor `Pair a b`:

```
--                     a 
--                     |
--                     v  b isn't here… 
instance Functor (Pair c) where  
  -- but here!
  --fmap :: (b -> x) -> Pair c b -> Pair c x
    fmap f (Pair (x,y)) = Pair (x, f y) 
                 --                ^^^ everything fine now.
```

But at this point, we're back at the original `(a,b)` instance.

Comment: :D ... he will get that badge eventually ;)

Comment: @Zeta It tripped me up as a non-native speaker, and when I finally figured out what it meant I thought I should spare other simple minds like myself. It may seem silly but from my experience teaching even the little things are important when you want to convey knowledge. :)

Comment: @kqr: It's fine. I thought that "oh oh" was more or less the same around the world.

Answer (score 0):

Both `newtype Pair a b` and `newtype Pair b a` are correct (as in, they type check). In the latter the type of the second element comes first, which is counterintuitive, although it may be more appropriate in your use case.

Comment: What do you mean by 'the type of the second element comes first'?